# Angular 4 material Sidenav doesn't close the menu after being selected

Tags: angular

I'm using the [angular Material Sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) it works well but with the problem that after select an option the menu still opens. It's so weird that this is mean to use as a navigation for small devices and the doc doesn't have any example using links

**App.component**

```
<md-sidenav-container>
     <md-sidenav #sidenav class="sidenav" mode="over">
    <ul class="sidenav">
      <li class="sidenav__list">
        <a class="sidenav__list__link " [routerLink]="['about']" >about</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </md-sidenav>

  <header>
    <div fxHide fxShow.lt-sm>
      <button class="btn__sidenav" md-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <i class="material-icons md-36">menu</i>
      </button>
    </div>

    </ng-template>
  </header>


    <div class="container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <wh-footer></wh-footer>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

basically, I have to load content for the about page and close the menu when the link is clicked, I dont know if I have to do manually or are there any directive or property that I can use

Answer (score 13):

**Option 1:**

You add `(click)="sidenav.close()"` inside `<a>`, which will close the sidenav when user selects 'About`.

```html
<a class="sidenav__list__link " [routerLink]="['about']" (click)="sidenav.close()">
    about
</a>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/wYaLD8Zho7zvtmCme7ms?p=preview)

If you don't want to add a `click` event in every `<a>` or `<li>`, you can put the `click` event inside `<ul>`. Sidenav will close for any `<li>` clicked/selected within that `<ul>`.

```html
<ul class="sidenav" (click)="sidenav.close()">
    <li class="sidenav__list">
        <a class="sidenav__list__link " [routerLink]="['about']" >about</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

**Option 2:**

Subscribe to router events and close the sidenav when a router event takes place.

```js
constructor(private _router: Router) { }

@ViewChild(MdSidenav) sidenav: MdSidenav;

ngOnInit() {
    this._router.events.subscribe(() => {
        if (this.isScreenSmall()) {
            this.sidenav.close();
        }
    });
}

isScreenSmall(): boolean {
    return window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT}px)`).matches;
}
```

[material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io) uses this option. Check the implementation of this code in [GitHub repo](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/component-sidenav/component-sidenav.ts).

Comment: Tha'ts exactly what I did, but if you check their website [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components) on mobile you won't see any event that closes the popup...it's like the background overlay that will close the menu if you click it..its something prebuild

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Made do some more research and I found what you said, material site uses `Router` `events` instead of `click`. I have updated the answer to include that option too :)

Answer (score 1):

For Angular 5, From [Nehal's Answer on Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45488962/7311767), just change :

```
@ViewChild(MdSidenav) sidenav: MdSidenav;
```

to

```
@ViewChild(MatSidenav) sidenav: MatSidenav;
```

Worked Like a Charm.
Also the sweetspot for small devices (tablets and under is 840px)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how do you use the SideNAv. If you want to emulate Android's Navigation Drawer, then you want it to auto-close upon selection.

My solution for the latest Angular Material version available (v12.0.2) consists on modifying the template so that the click handler of each element toggles the sidenav:

```html
<mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/section1'" (click)="sidenav.toggle()"> Section 1 title </a>
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/section2'" (click)="sidenav.toggle()"> Section 2 title </a>
        ...
        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/sectionN'" (click)="sidenav.toggle()"> Section N title </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
```